# ASP.NET Core Azure deployment missing configuration files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, configuration

I am trying to publish an ASP.NET Core MVC Application to Azure. It works in common but my configuration files like `mycongif.json`, which is in the root of the application, is never be deployed. If I declare the config file as non-optional, I receive an HTTP 500 error, because the file couldn't be found.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using project.json, make sure you have something like this in there:

```
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config",
      "Views",
      "myconfig.json"
    ]
},
```

This specifies what folders and files should be included in the publish.

In the new .csproj format you should have something like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="**\*.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="compiler\resources\**\*" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\**\*;Views\**\*;Areas\**\Views;myconfig.json;web.config">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you! Where to hell found you that information, I'm googling since hours :-)